# How to import Photoshop Shapes in Flash

Tags: flash, import, shapes

I'm looking for a method to import Photoshop shapes intro flash. I want to import them as vectors not bitmaps. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File, Export path to Illustrator.
Then in Flash, Import.

Answer (score 0):

you have to export them in Illustrator first 
then 
file ---> import 
in flash